# Returning a dictionary with all dates between a start and an end date

Tags: python, django, date, dictionary

I have a Calendar on one of my django views. I am trying to return a dictionary with a list of dates between a start and an end date.

At the moment, I can only return a list of start dates or end dates. I need these along with all the days in between to be part of the dictionary.

```
class HolidayCalendar(HTMLCalendar):

    def __init__(self, holiday):
        super(HolidayCalendar, self).__init__()
        self.holiday = self.holiday_days(holiday)

        #some formatting

    def holiday_days(self, holiday):
        #don't actually know how this works.... 
        field = lambda holiday: holiday.start_date.day
        # field = lambda holiday: holiday.end_date.day
        return dict(
        [(day, list(items)) for day, items in groupby(holiday, field)]
    )
```

In all honesty, I don't fully understand this at all...
This is the view that calls this:

```
def holiday(request):
    #some code
    date_today = datetime.now()
    year = date_today.year
    month = date_today.month
    my_holidays = Holiday.objects.order_by('start_date').filter(
        Q(start_date__year=year, start_date__month=month) | Q(end_date__year=year, end_date__month=month)
    )
    cal = HolidayCalendar(my_holidays).formatmonth(year, month)
    #form stuff
    context = {
        "holidayform": holidayform,
        "calendar": mark_safe(cal),
    }
    return render(request, "tande/calendar.html", context)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Having start and end dates you can just add a `timedelta` of 1 day to the former until you reach the latter. Something like this:

```
day_delta = timedelta(1,0,0)
next = start_date
days = []
while (end_date - next) < day_delta:
    next = next + day
    days.append(next)
```

So now `days` will have a list of all the days between `start_date` and `end_date`

Comment: Yeah I can see how that works that's useful. However, I'm not managing to integrate something like that with my code. Because I can't access the start_date and end_date because it's not a request... so I just get a 'Not in queryset' or 'Name not defined' error

Comment: You have `field = lambda holiday: holiday.start_date.day` so it seems that `holiday.start_date` is a `datetime` object, there also seems to be a `holiday.end_date` which I assume is another `datetime`.

Comment: They're both date fields in my holiday model. They're used in the holiday view to filter what comes up and I want holiday to show start_date to end_date on the calendar if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, I didn't need a dictionary in the end I just used a list:

```
class HolidayCalendar(HTMLCalendar):

    def __init__(self, holiday):
        super(HolidayCalendar, self).__init__()
        self.holiday = self.holiday_days(holiday)


def holiday_days(self, holiday):
        day_delta = timedelta(1,0,0)
        holidays = Holiday.objects.all()
        days = []
        for balloon in holidays:
            next = balloon.start_date
            end = balloon.end_date
            while (end - next) > day_delta:
                next = next + day_delta
                days.append(next)
            start_day = balloon.start_date
            days.append(start_day)
            days.append(end)
        holiday = []
        for purple in days:
            pink = purple.day
            holiday.append(pink)           
        return holiday
```